# Grouping functions from an R package

Tags: r, module, package, grouping, r-package

## Context

I am developing an R package which contains over a hundred page-long functions grouped into 10 different themes.

## Desired behavior

I would like the user to be able to take such themes into consideration when calling functions.

For example, instead of calling `foo()`, the user would have to do either

```r
load(theme1) # or whatever would be used to load a subgroup of functions
foo()
```

or something like

```r
theme1$foo()
```

What I want to prevent the user from doing is directly loading the package and calling the function without taking the theme into consideration, i.e. `library(package); foo()`.

## What I have tried

I have used the [modules package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=modules) to accomplish the latter solution in a [previous package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=LOGAN), but this time around the published version of that package doesn't work very well due to how my functions are interdependent (I've opened a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/wahani/modules/issues/28) on the topic).

I also thought about coding my own solution, maybe something simple involving the creationg of a `sublibrary()` function that exports only a few functions at a time, but I didn't get anywhere with that.

Of course, I guess publishing 10 different packages would also technically work, but I think that's too clumsy a solution to consider.

## Question

Apart from using modules, is there a way to implement either of the functionalities above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea of how you could achieve the `sublibrary` function. In this case we will use it to load a small subsection of `ggplot2`

```r
sublibrary <- function(theme) {
  subgroups <- 
    list(basic   = list(ggplot = ggplot2::ggplot,
                        aes = ggplot2::aes,
                        geom_line = ggplot2::geom_line,
                        geom_point = ggplot2::geom_point),
        advanced = list(scale_color_manual = ggplot2::scale_color_manual,
                        theme = ggplot2::theme))
  
  attach(list2env(subgroups[[theme]]))
}
```

This means that without loading an entire package I could do:

```
sublibrary("basic")

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, color = Species)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

In reality, the `subgroup` object would be stored outside the function, in a list or environment within the package namespace.

Comment: This seems to do the trick, thank you _so_ much! I had played around with `attach` to solve this, but I didn't know about `list2env`, so I couldn't get far. I'm stoked about how well it also handled the function documentation (i.e., I had to make the functions internal so they would stay hidden until loading, but after loading I could still use `?` to open their docs).

Comment: I don't think `attach` will pass CRAN checks.  See *Good Practice* section in `?attach`.

Answer (score 2):

Object oriented programming could be used here where `theme1` is a class or an object instantiated from the class and the functions associated with it are the methods.  There are a number of alternatives here including R reference classes (more info via `?ReferenceClasses`), [R6 package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=R6), [proto package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=proto), the [R.oo package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=R6) and function scoping (more info via `demo("scoping")` .

For example using the proto package:

```
library(proto)

theme1 <- proto(
  foo = function(.) print("foo"),
  bar = function(.) print("bar")
)

theme1$foo()
## [1] "foo"
theme1$bar()
## [1] "bar"
```

If it is just a matter of grouping and if you don't need local storage  or inheritance then we could even use a list:

```
theme1 <- list(foo = function() print("foo"),
               bar = function() print("bar"))

theme1$foo()
## [1] "foo"
theme1$bar()
## [1] "bar"
```

A number of other OO approaches could be used but they involve creating a class which is then used to create a single object (which is an extra step); however, they do support the $ syntax of the question.

Using R6 we have:

```
library(R6)

Theme1 = R6Class("theme1",
  public = list(
    foo = function() print("foo"),
    bar = function() print("bar")
  )
)

theme1 <- Theme1$new() # generate a Theme1 object

theme1$foo()
## [1] "foo"
theme1$bar()
## [1] "bar"
```

or using Reference Classes (no packages needed):

```
setRefClass(
  "Theme1",
  methods = list(
    foo = function() print("foo"),
    bar = function() print("bar")
  )
)

theme1 <- Theme1()  # generate Theme1 object

theme1$foo()
## [1] "foo"
theme1$bar()
## [1] "bar"
```

or using function scoping (no packages needed):

```
Theme1 <- function() list(
  foo = function() print("foo"),
  bar = function() print("bar")
)

theme1 <- Theme1()

theme1$foo()
## [1] "foo"
theme1$bar()
## [1] "bar"
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to make such a complete answer! I'm still getting used to S4, can hardly believe they already to up to 6! xD